# Where does Gradle log to in context of TestKit's GradleRunner?

Tags: gradle

My Spock specification starts the Gradle build with the option --debug using the TestKit's GradleRunner like this:

```
GradleRunner.create()
            .withProjectDir(testProjectDir.root)
            .withPluginClasspath(pluginClasspath)
            .withArguments('myCustomTask', '--debug', '--stacktrace').build()
```

But I can't find Gradle's output anywhere. Neither on the console nor in JUnit's output under the build directory nor in the temporary directory used by the GradleRunner.

Gradle Version is 4.9, JUnit Version 4.12.

Answer (score 0):

GradleRunner buffers the output of the launched Gradle build internally in memory. You can access it with `getOutput()` of `BuildResult` returned by `GradleRunner.build()`. Alternatively, you can call `GradleRunner.forwardOutput()` which duplicates the output to `System.out` of GradleRunner.